# Replacing a query with SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y is not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**What does this query try to achieve?**

```sql
SELECT * FROM X WHERE (X.Y in (select Y from X))
```

As far as I figured, it is yielding me the same result as

```sql
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y is not NULL
```

Is there anything more to the first query? The first query is actually very slow with a large dataset and hence I want to know whether I can replace it with the second query.

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output from them.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, but please do check it against your actual data to make sure both versions return identical result sets.

Comment: Your first query will query the whole table and second one maybe will use index to optimize speed.So, the  second query is very well

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. Always name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: 1st query is equivalent to `where y=y`, whoch also filters NULLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the two queries are equivalent.

It is unclear, why the first query was written this way. Maybe it looked different once.

As is, your second query is better, because it is easier to read and understand (and even faster as you say).

Comment: . . I am guessing the OP oversimplified the example and left out a correlation clause.  But the queries as presented are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

your second query is perfect than the 1st one

because in 1st query you may get abnormal(null) result in case if column Y  contains `null` value but you will not get abnormal result in 2nd one if `null` values contain in column Y.

So based on values of your table two query will behave two different way

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the difference?